# NetBeans IDE still on 6.9 version?

Tags: package-management, netbeans

I wonder why NetBeans 6.9 is still in Software Center and is not replaced by 7.0?

I mean, the new Firefox package is published within a few hours after release, why is the NetBeans package not updated yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once Ubuntu is released only security fixes or fixes to major flaws are published in the stable release. See here for the policy:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates

Certain software, like the Firefox can be [granted exceptions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates/MicroReleaseExceptions) based on special circumstances, but generally speaking if you want a new version of something you'll have to find a PPA for it, see if it has been backported, or build it yourself.

Comment: In the case of Netbeans, there's no need for building it. There might be a PPA, but I'm not sure. I do know that Netbeans themselves provide a nice, easy, install script for each version. You literally download it, mark as executable, and double-click it. The only caveat is that it installs alongside any existing versions (though it will import from older versions on first run, so once that's done, you can remove the old versions), so you will need to update your shortcuts manually.

Comment: Thanks. I have installed it manually. It's ok except it does not play nice with unity launcher. This means that you will end up using outdated apps most of the time. Thanks anyway.

Comment: How does it not play nice with the launcher? Had no problems in that regard so far ...

Answer (score 0):

Sun stopped officially supporting Ruby editing in Netbeans starting from 7.0, although it was working in 6.9.  We have a major legacy Ruby app that requires version 6.9.  Please don't let it go away.